# Is there way to change audio language in youtube iframe api?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is there parameter for change audio language?
I want change audio Langauge like `cc_lang_pref = "ko"`
but there are no parameter name like `audio_lang_pref`.
Is there way to change audio language in iframe api?
I tried `audio_lang_pref = "ko"` but doesn't work

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to force that. Try to use `hl`  parameter for text language, maybe it helps